# Swapping the element using strcpy not working in the array

Tags: c, arrays, strcpy

I was trying to swap the elements in the array (which is extremely basic, but when I try to change the index of the array, it mess up the whole array)

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int swap;
    int position;
    char temp[1000];
    char *i;
    swap = 1;

    while (swap == 1)
    {
        swap = 0;
        position = 1;
        while (position < (argc - 1))
        {
            if (strcmp(argv[position], argv[position + 1]) > 0)
            {
                strcpy(temp, argv[position + 1]);
                strcpy(argv[position], argv[position + 1]);
                strcpy(argv[position + 1], temp);
            }
            position++;
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

from the code above, if I put "hi" and "hello", instead of printing 
"hello" "hi", it brings "hello" "lo" which is super bizarre.

However, when I just simply use pointer (the code below), it works flawlessly.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int swap;
    int position;
    char temp[1000];
    char *i;
    swap = 1;

    while (swap == 1)
    {
        swap = 0;
        position = 1;
        while (position < (argc - 1))
        {
            if (strcmp(*(argv + position), *(argv +position + 1)) > 0 )
            {
                i = *(argv + position);
                *(argv + position) = *(argv + (position + 1));
                *(argv + position + 1) = i;
                swap = 1;
            }
            position++;
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

could you tell me what is wrong with the first way of doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments, to which the argv vector points, is usually structured like this:

```
"foo\0barbaz\0quux\0"
```

with `argv[1]` pointing to the "f", `argv[2]` pointing to "b" and `argv[3]` pointing to "q".

Now you can easily see, that you mess up the arguments and the pointers to them if you swap these naively; for example, if you swap "foo" and "barbaz", it looks like this:

```
"barbaz\0foo\0quux\0".
```

Fine, but now `argv[2]` still points to the same location, which is the second "a" in barbaz!

Your first method is even more flawed since you use the pointers from the `argv` vector as destinations. First, you copy `foo` to `argv[2]`:

```
"foo\0foo\0az\0quux\0"
```

and then `barbaz` to `argv[1]`

```
"barbaz\0\0az\0quux\0"
```

You see, this is completely messed up.

This is why your method doesn't work without also adjusting the pointers in the `argv`-vector.

Your second proposed method should indeed work flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Ctx's answer regarding the layout of `*argv[]`you have an additional problem with your array index:

Wrong index:

```
        {
            strcpy(temp, argv[position + 1]);  // You store from index +1
            strcpy(argv[position], argv[position + 1]);
            strcpy(argv[position + 1], temp);  // Restore into same index.
        }
```

As you store and restore the same index, the copying to `temp` does not have any effect here. You end up with two copies of the same string.

Correct index:

```
        if (strcmp(*(argv + position), *(argv +position + 1)) > 0 )
        {
            i = *(argv + position);  // <<== Store from pos
            *(argv + position) = *(argv + (position + 1));
            *(argv + position + 1) = i; // <<== Restore into pos+1
            swap = 1;
        }
```

You store `position` and restore into `position + 1`. This is how swapping works.